# Add a div to wrap a content inside a WordPress widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress, widget, themes

I have created a widget in functions.php and i was able to display them on my index.php , i use the widget manager drop and drag to display the content i would like to add but i am confused how i may wrap those tags inside a div and give it a class name in order to style this specific block section.

This is functions.php

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpdevs_sidebars');
    function wpdevs_sidebars(){

        // Register 3 widget areas
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name'  =>  'Service 1',
                'id'    =>  'services-1',
                'description'   =>  '1st Service Area',
                'before_widget'  =>  '<div class="widget-wrapper-1">',
                'after_widget'  =>  '</div>',
                'before_title'  =>  '<h4 class="widget-title-1">',
                'after_title'  =>  '</h4>'
            )
        );
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name'  =>  'Service 2',
                'id'    =>  'services-2',
                'description'   =>  '2nd Service Area',
                'before_widget'  =>  '<div class="widget-wrapper-2">',
                'after_widget'  =>  '</div>',
                'before_title'  =>  '<h4 class="widget-title-2">',
                'after_title'  =>  '</h4>'
            )
        );        
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name'  =>  'Service 3',
                'id'    =>  'services-3',
                'description'   =>  '3rd Service Area',
                'before_widget'  =>  '<div class="widget-wrapper-3">',
                'after_widget'  =>  '</div>',
                'before_title'  =>  '<h4 class="widget-title-3">',
                'after_title'  =>  '</h4>'
            )
        );
}
```

And this is my index.php

```
<div class="bloc_items">

    <div class="services-item-1">
        <?php 
            if(is_active_sidebar('services-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('services-1');
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="services-item-2">
        <?php 
            if(is_active_sidebar('services-2')){
                dynamic_sidebar('services-2');
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="services-item-3">
        <?php 
            if(is_active_sidebar('services-3')){
                dynamic_sidebar('services-3');
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'before_widget'  =>  '<div class="widget-wrapper-1">',
```

This line is already a wrapper around your widget. You can use it for styling.

Comment: Thank you Tyzia for the help